# Ansible-Merge two nested json files into single file of Json format

Tags: json, ansible, append

I am having two json and want to append one into another and save them in one file. I have done a set fact to read the values and put them in a variable using following:

```
- name: Set json combine to add new event
  set_fact:
     event_json_create: "{{ lookup('file', 'event_template.json') }}" 

- name: Set json combine to get the existing list of events
  set_fact:
     event_json_existing: "{{ lookup('file', 'notification.json') }}"
```

Now I want to append the event_json_create to event_json_existing.

The event_json_create looks like this:

```
"event_json_create": {
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [{
        "Events": [
            "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
        ],
        "Filter": {
            "Key": {
                "FilterRules": [{
                    "Name": "prefix",
                    "Value": [
                        "keying_service/response/"
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:xyz"
    }]
}
```

The event_json_existing looks like this:

```
"event_json_existing": {
           "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
               {
                   "Events": [
                       "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
                   ],
                   "Filter": {
                       "Key": {
                           "FilterRules": [
                               {
                                   "Name": "Prefix",
                                   "Value": "staging/inbound/Source_Contact/ac/input_fia/"
                               }
                           ]
                       }
                   },
                   "Id": "Eventtry",
                   "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:******:function:abc"
               }
           ]
       }
```

How can I append the two json in ansible ensuring that both json are under major group: LambdaFunctionConfigurations and then I can write this into a json file. So the output I expect:

```
{
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [{
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ],
            "Filter": {
                "Key": {
                    "FilterRules": [{
                        "Name": "prefix",
                        "Value": [
                            "keying_service/response/"
                        ]
                    }]
                }
            },
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:xyz"
        },
        {
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ],
            "Filter": {
                "Key": {
                    "FilterRules": [{
                        "Name": "Prefix",
                        "Value": "staging/inbound/Source_Contact/ac/input_fia/"
                    }]
                }
            },
            "Id": "Eventtry",
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help!

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, quoting `Minimal: The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This template

```
shell> cat events.json.j2
{{ events|to_nice_json }}
```

and the tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        events: "{{ {'LambdaFunctionConfigurations':
                     ([event_json_create.LambdaFunctionConfigurations.0] +
                      [event_json_existing.LambdaFunctionConfigurations.0])} }}"
    - template:
        src: events.json.j2
        dest: events.json
```

give

```
shell> cat events.json 
{
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
        {
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ],
            "Filter": {
                "Key": {
                    "FilterRules": [
                        {
                            "Name": "prefix",
                            "Value": [
                                "keying_service/response/"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:*******:function:xyz"
        },
        {
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ],
            "Filter": {
                "Key": {
                    "FilterRules": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Prefix",
                            "Value": "staging/inbound/Source_Contact/ac/input_fia/"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Id": "Eventtry",
            "LambdaFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:******:function:abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is this step used here for?shell> cat events.json.j2
{{ events|to_nice_json }}  How should I use following in ansible?

Comment: What is your preferred command to display the content of a file?

Comment: Please have a look.I have modified the ques where I want to keep everything in the file event_json_existing along with adding the new content into it under LambdaFunctionConfigurations. I have added TopicConfigurations as another group there.  I will be printing the content in json file. Thanks for you help  in advance

Comment: You've changed the question so that my answer is no more valid. This is not going to work. To proceed, you might want to restore the question and open a new one.